# Pandas conditional map/fill/replace

Tags: python, pandas

```
d1=pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c','c'],'y':[-1,-2,-3,0]})
d2=pd.DataFrame({'x':['d','c','a','b'],'y':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]})
```

I want to replace `d1.y` where y<0 with the correspondent `y` in d2. It's something like vlookup in Excel. The core problem is replace y according to x rather than just simply manipulate y. What I want is

```
Out[40]: 
   x    y
0  a  0.3
1  b  0.4
2  c  0.2
3  c  0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with condition:

```
s = d2.set_index('x')['y']
d1.loc[d1.y < 0, 'y'] = d1['x'].map(s)
print (d1)

   x    y
0  a  0.3
1  b  0.4
2  c  0.2
3  c  0.0
```

Comment: Sorry my sample data is to easy. The core problem is replace y according to x rather simply manipulate the y. I will update my post now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`d1.loc[d1.y < 0, 'y'] = d2.loc[d1.y < 0, 'y']`

Comment: Sorry my sample data is to easy. The core problem is replace y according to x rather simply manipulate the y. I will update my post now.